# Is it possible to assign cases to Queue based on subject line, which contains the word "Theft"

Tags: formula, case, assignment-rules, queue

Is it possible to assign cases based on subject line contains the word theft.

I have tried creating an assignment rule, which is not working.

Please suggest me the possible ways in configuration, if not customization.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing same issue. I followed below steps :

> > 1) Go to set up-> Customize -> Case -> Case Assignment rules. Here, I created new Rule and activated it. (I didn't use standard one. Deactivate the standard one).
> >
> > > 2) I added my new rule into that newly created Custom Rule.
> > >       Then it worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created a assignment rule as:-
Case: Subject CONTAINS Theft
 Also,you should check is whether your assignment rule is Active or not.If not then please activate it and try creating case again and check accordingly.
[image]

Regards,
Suraj

Comment: Its already activated. Still its not assigning.

Comment: When creating a case,case assignment rules are not applied if "Assign using active assignment rules" is not checked.
I hope you are checking the "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox to true while creating a case.

Comment: Its checked-in by Default in layout properties(Assign using active assignment rules).